# Animate.css conflict with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, animate.css

I've got a problem with an animation from animate.css
Every animation that enters from the right, extends my container. This happens only in chrome, and only with animations from right. Anyone knows a workaround?

Here's the problem in action:
http://www.andibauer.at/wp-themes/arkane/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do following, for example:

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="../" class="animated bounceInRight" />
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

The rule *"overflow: hidden"* to *div* with class *"container"* banishes the horizontal scroll for the animations from right.

Comment: That is indeed working, but an ugly workaround as the animation then runs only in the container which is not the whole page. And then the animated object appears in the middle of the page.

Comment: The .container should be inside the body and the .container add width: 100% with the overflow: hidden For example http://jsfiddle.net/x9sfaapm/embedded/result/

Comment: But my container isn't 100% width (and can't be). That's where the problem comes in I suppose. Maybe it's caused by bootstrap (which I am using here). Or do I have to use one more wrapper?

Comment: Yeah, you must have two wrappers for example to the first wrapper -> overflow:hidden and width:100%, second wrapper could be the width whatever, inside the second wrapper put the element with animated bounceInRight. If you want, send me an example of your code using "jsFiddle"

Comment: Hah, finally I got it. Thanks mate.